# Who does the work in the post-apocalypse society in Kingsman: The Secret Service?

Tags: kingsman-the-secret-service

In the 2014 film Kingsman: The Secret Service, our megalomaniac villain Richmond Valentine plans to

> severely reduce the population of the human race by distributing free sim cards capable of sending a signal which causes people to be uncontrollably violent, killing others at random.

Having done this, he means to

> restart society anew, with a collection of the 'great and the good', made up of celebrities, nobility and politicians. In short, a group of those privileged people who are patently used to having things done for them.

I'm not sure he's thought this through:

> In a post-apocalypse society of the wealthy and privileged, who would know how to produce food? And who would be willing to do menial work such as cleaning, refuse collection and food preparation.

So my question is this:

Does Richmond Valentine have a plan for human society going forward? How is his utopian society supposed to work?

Answer (score 2):

His plan does make sense.  Not everyone would die in the mayhem that he would unleash.

The effect of the signal is not permanent.  There would be survivors amongst those who had not been chosen. This is shown earlier when Galahad. Walks out of the church.   Survivors who would presumably be the strongest and fittest in their particular part of the world.

Valentine and his chosen ones would employ (enslave) them as a new underclass supporting his brave new world.

Comment: I'm not so sure, I mean, why would they want to serve the rich and powerful people? Who made them kill their peers, who would be responsible for the death of those important to you?

Comment: I don't know about you, but I'd let the toffs starve.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [Richmond Valentines description on wikia](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Richmond_Valentine) there is a table with his goals.

> 1 Goals:
>
> ! - Kill Eggs Unwin and the Kingsman organization
>   "Change the world" by giving away phones containing his SIM card which causes humans to become uncontrollably violent so as to kill a majority of the human race and presumably lead the survivors (failed)
>
> ! - Kill Harry Hart (succeeded)

Now, regarding your answer, he does have a small army at his base, and he is smart enough to make the survivors obey him.